# posix time comparison in r not behaving the same in for loop and apply function

Tags: r, time, apply

Hello i am having an interesting issue with R

When i do :

```
touchtimepairs = structure(list(v..length.v.. = structure(c(1543323677.254, 1543323678.137, 1543323679.181, 1543323679.918, 1543323680.729, 1543323681.803, 1543323682.523, 1543323682.977,1543323683.519, 1543323684.454), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CEST"),v.2.length.v.. = structure(c(1543323678.137, 1543323679.181, 1543323679.918, 1543323680.729, 1543323681.803, 1543323682.523, 1543323682.977, 1543323683.519, 1543323684.454, 1543323690.793), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CEST")), .Names = c("v..length.v..", "v.2.length.v.."), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

data = data.frame(a = seq(1,10), b = seq(21,30), posixtime = touchtimepairs[,1])



for(x in seq(nrow(touchtimepairs))){
    a = data$[data$posixtime < touchtimepairs[x,2],]
}
```

it works without a problem i get results back but when i try to use apply

```
a = apply(touchtimepairs, 1, 
          function(x) data[data$posixtime < x[2],])
```

it does not work anymore, I get an empty data frame. The same happens with the subset() command. 
Interestingly when i do > instead of < it works !

```
a = apply(touchtimepairs, 1, 
          function(x) data[data$posixtime > x[2],])
```

Then there is another issue:

apply in the case of the > comparison gives another result than the for loop

1951 lines with  apply and 
1897 with the for loop

can anyone reproduce this behavior?

The posix time has also miliseconds if that is of any interest

Many thanks

Comment: Could you possibly post a small subset of your data together with intended output, ideally with intentions? That would really help!

Comment: Is `touchtimepairs` a `data.frame`? Are all the columns the same `class`? If not, then `apply(touchtimepairs,...)` always always always messes with your data in some form. The only time that will work as desired is if all of the columns in your frame are of the same class. Suggest you change your anon-func to be `function(x) {browser();...;}` and take a look at `str(x)`, perhaps it would be exactly what you think it is.

Comment: both columns of touchtimepairs are "POSIXct" "POSIXt"  classes, thanks for the browser tip and indeed , after calling apply x becomes a character class

Comment: I still cannot reproduce anything. Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. In this specific case, consider providing a small set of each frame, perhaps 3-5 rows each, where you know you'll have a fixed set of matches. Please don't paste into comments. Please use the output from `dput`. It makes a difference.

Comment: I dont know exactly how to paste posixtime with ms into the code panel need a sec :-), no non base r code needed

Comment: *"dont know"* ... please read the link, it's there: `dput(head(touchtimepairs))` (and again for your other frame). BTW: *all* `POSIXt` objects have milliseconds, regardless of what it shows on the console. Realize that there is a difference between what is stored and what is shown. `pi` is a good example ... do you really want R to try to show you all of the digits?

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the  reproducible example some edits are needed i see

Comment: For me: `apply(touchtimepairs[1:2,], 1, function(x) {browser();x})` and then `class(x)` gives `character`. I'll expand my previous warning about using `apply` with frames of mixed-class: don't use `apply` with frames that have anything other than `numeric`/`integer`. (This might be related to the warning I get with your data: `unknown timezone 'CEST'`. Edit: nope, that's not it.)

Comment: Yes i can reproduce it now, so i should reformat the data in lists and use lapply instead

Comment: What ultimately are you trying to do? You have two columns in `touchtimepairs`, it seems like you want to use them both for something ... ranges of times, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, as r2evans said apply and mixed dataframes do not mix, and the idea is to use    `l = split(touchtimepairs, seq(nrow(touchtimepairs)))` and then `lapply(l , function(x){data[data$posixtime < x[[2]],]} )`

Comment: I want to filter my data which comes from a big xml file and is >20 mb by time intervals and save everything separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your data *inside* the `apply` anonymous function, you'll see the symptom that is causing your trouble.

```
apply(touchtimepairs, 1, class)
#           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10 
# "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

(It should be returning a 2-row matrix with `POSIXct` and `POSIXt`.) I should also note that I kept getting warnings about `unknown timezone 'CEST'`. I fixed it temporarily with `attr(touchtimepairs[[1]], "tzone") <- "UTC"`, though that's just a kludge to stop the warnings on my console. It doesn't fix the problem and might just be my system. :-)

If you are trying to use both columns of `touchtimepairs`, you have two options:

1. If you really only need one of `touchtimepairs` at a time, then `lapply` will work:

   ```
   lapply(touchtimepairs[[1]],
          function(x) subset(data, posixtime < x))
   ```
2. If you need to use both columns at the same time, use an index on the rows:

   ```
   lapply(seq_len(nrow(touchtimepairs)),
          function(i) subset(data, posixtime < touchtimepairs[i,2]))
   ```

   (where you'd also reference `touchtimepairs[i,1]` somehow).
3. Especially if you are trying to use both columns simultaneously, you can use `Map`:

   ```
   Map(function(a, b) subset(data, a < posixtime & posixtime <= b),
       touchtimepairs[[1]], touchtimepairs[[2]])
   ```

   (This does not return anything in your sample data, so either the data is not the best representative sample, or you are not intending to use it in this fashion. Most likely the latter, I'm just guessing :-)

   The biggest difference between `Map` and the `*apply` family is that it accepts one *or more* vectors/lists and zips them together. As an example of this "zipper" effect:

   ```
   Map(func, 1:3, 11:13)
   ```

   is effectively calling:

   ```
   func(1, 11)
   func(2, 12)
   func(3, 13)
   ```